# No ActionBar and no StatusBar in android studio 3.3

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ide, android-studio-3.3

In the below image you can see that there is no `ActionBar` and `StatusBar` in the preview of any XML layout file, if anyone is facing the same issue and has solution please post it.

[image: Latest android studio 3.3]

Comment: This could possibly because you might have selected NoActionBar theme. on your `AppTheme` try adjusting it to a different theme.

Comment: Change your theme.

Comment: Please Check answer below. solution is there on your IDE itself.

Comment: Have you got your issue resolved?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**I faced the same issue, and got this:**

> 1. No `ActionBar` visible

[image]

> 2. Change a setting for Show Layout Decorations (By Default it is unchecked, just check it and ActionBar will be there)

[image]

> 3. Visible `ActionBar`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Select the theme from above which have action bar by clicking where AppTheme is written in top pane of preview window.